# How to have two or more simultaneously UIView Animation blocks running at the same time?

Tags: swift, animation

Basically I have code like this:

```
class ExampleViewController : UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var view1 : UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var view2 : UIView!

    func animate1() {
        view1.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:100, height:100);
        UIView.animate (withDuration: 0.2) {
            view1.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:100, width:100, height:100);
        }
    }

    func animate2() {
        view2.frame = CGRect(x:100, y:0, width:100, height:100);
        UIView.animate (withDuration: 0.2) {
            view2.frame = CGRect(x:100, y:100, width:100, height:100);
        }
    }

    func routineSingle() {
        animate1();
    }

    func routineDouble() {
        animate1();
        animate2();
    }

}

let example = ExampleViewController();
```

If I call `example.routineSingle()`, the `view1` moved flawlessly. But if I call `example.routineDouble()`, only the `view2` moved animatedly. The `view1` is suddenly shown at the end location without animation.

How can I call such `example.routineDouble()` and see both views' animation paralel on screen?

Answer (score 0):

I must admit this is weird. Have you tried moving both initial frame set and animation content to the same method (frame set in the same animation block)?

I would also try out a UIViewAnimationOptions.beginFromCurrentState option

```
view1.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:100, height:100)
view2.frame = CGRect(x:100, y:0, width:100, height:100)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: [.beginFromCurrentState], animations: {
    self.view1.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:100, width:100, height:100)
    self.view2.frame = CGRect(x:100, y:100, width:100, height:100)
}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Yes I have, and it works. There's no problem if the animation is just 1 animation block. The problem is different part of the app might trigger different animation at different time. So for example I press a button where it cause the button to animate. At the same time, there can be a push notification comes in and trigger mail icon animation on the top right. When this happen, the animation that's started first will be "cancelled" and goes straight to the end result, when the second animation started. This way, I cannot put both object in a single animation block. It is weird indeed. :(

Answer (score 0):

Why do you change the view-s frame directly? As I can see you have IBOutlets.

I suggest connecting constraints of these views, set the constraints `.constant` or `.multiplier` values when you want to move them and in the animation block simply call `layoutIfNeeded`.

I think this worths a try.

Also if you have your values where you want your views to animate to assigned to variables you can have a common animation block for your views.

Example:

```
let yourFirstCondition = false
let yourSecondCondition = false

var firstViewPosition: CGPoint {
    get {
        if yourFirstCondition {
            return CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
        } else {
            return CGPoint.zero
        }
    }
}

var secondViewPosition: CGPoint {
    get {
        if yourSecondCondition {
            return CGPoint(x: 200, y: 100)
        } else {
            return CGPoint.zero
        }
    }
}
```

And then have a common block where you animate the firstView to firstViewPosition and the second view to secondViewPosition.